# KKT conditions for min-cost flow QP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm working on a convex quadratic separable min-cost flow problem with the following structure:

$P = \{\min \frac{1}{2}x^tQx + qx : Ex = b, 0 \leq x \leq u\}$

But I'm stuck on deriving the KKT conditions to solve the problem.

Can someone help me with the computation?

Comment: Posted also on MO: [KKT conditions for min-cost flow QP](https://mathoverflow.net/q/335357) It is [recommended](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) to link question to the other copies when [meta-tag:cross-posting].